# Trying to use static column headings in VS designer for Listview in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, listview

I've created a form and added a listview (lsTest) through VS Designer (VS 2010) and then added columns to it. For each of the columns, I've added a column heading and a value for Text property. For instance, the first column is named col1 and the text I want to display for it is 'This is Col1':
[Column definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7hLm.png)

In the code, I have a simple SQL Select statement to pull data from a SQL Server table and load a dataset (dsTest). I then read through the dataset and load the columns from each dataset row into a new listview item. This data load works fine (I can see in debug that items are being added to the listview). I also put one of the SQL columns into the listview column's tag as it's the data's primary key (this is why the for loop stops at Count - 2, the key is the last column). This is the data load:

```
For iRow = 0 To dsTest.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    Dim lvItem As New ListViewItem
    lvItem.Tag = dsTest.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)(dsTest.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1).ToString()
    For iCol = 0 To dsTest.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 2
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(Trim(dsTest.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)(iCol).ToString()))
    Next
    lstTest.Items.Add(lvItem)
Next
```

The problem is that the columns do not show at all when the listview is displayed. After some research, I tried adding columnheadings using the SQL field names.

```
For iCol = 0 To dsTest.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 2
    dsTest.Columns.Add(dsShares.Tables(0).Columns(iCol).ColumnName)
Next
```

The columns now display, but they're using the SQL field names as the headings (which I would expect as that is what I did in the code). But the thing is, I don't want to use the SQL field names for the headings; I want to use the defined column headings that I added in Design.
I then tried looping through lstTest.Items, and using the Text attribute to populate the columnheadings. If I do this BEFORE loading the data, the For..next loop executes 0 times. If I do this AFTER loading the data, the loop executes the correct number of times but the headings are empty.

Here are my attempts and the results:

### Example 1 - Data load only

```
For iRow = 0 To dsTest.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 2
    Dim lvItem As New ListViewItem
    lvItem.Tag = dsTest.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)(dsTest.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1).ToString()
    For iCol = 0 To dsTest.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 2
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(Trim(dsTest.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)(iCol).ToString()))
    Next
    lstTest.Items.Add(lvItem)
Next
```

Result: Data loads in lstTest.Items but nothing shows

### Example 2 - Data load, headings from SQL columns

```
    For iCol = 0 To dsTest.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 2
       lstTest.Columns.Add(dsTest.Tables(0).Columns(iCol).ColumnName)
   Next
   For iRow = 0 To dsTest.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 2
        Dim lvItem As New ListViewItem
        lvItem.Tag = dsTest.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)(dsTest.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1).ToString()
        For iCol = 0 To dsTest.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 2
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(Trim(dsTest.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)(iCol).ToString()))
        Next
        lstTest.Items.Add(lvItem)
    Next
```

Result: Data shows with SQL column names as headings

### Example 3 - Data load, headings from column.items before data load

```
For iCol = 0 To lstTest.Items.Count - 2
    lstTest.Columns.Add(lstTest.Items(iCol).Text)
Next
For iRow = 0 To dsTest.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 2
    Dim lvItem As New ListViewItem
    lvItem.Tag = dsTest.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)(dsTest.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1).ToString()
    For iCol = 0 To dsTest.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 2
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(Trim(dsTest.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)(iCol).ToString()))
    Next
    lstTest.Items.Add(lvItem)
Next
```

Result: First loop executes 0 times; data shows but no column headings

### Example 4 - Data load, headings from column.items after data load

```
        For iRow = 0 To dsTest.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 2
            Dim lvItem As New ListViewItem
            lvItem.Tag = dsTest.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)(dsTest.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1).ToString()
            For iCol = 0 To dsTest.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 2
                lvItem.SubItems.Add(Trim(dsTest.Tables(0).Rows(iRow)(iCol).ToString()))
            Next
            lstTest.Items.Add(lvItem)
        Next
        For iCol = 0 To lstTest.Items.Count - 2
            lstTest.Columns.Add(lstTest.Items(iCol).Text)
        Next
```

Result: Second loop executes correct number of times; data shows but no column headings

I've searched and searched, but all the examples I could find load the column headings from within the code. I can't find any examples where the headings from Designer are used.

Is there something I am missing here? Or can't VB.net/VS do what I want?

Thanks in advance for your help